# Purpose of dbplyr::collapse function

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

I do not understand when/why someone would use the `dbplyr::collapse` function.

I understand it creates a subquery, but where/when would this be beneficial?

The R documentation does not provide any real clarity or examples.

Comment: Have you read through all of the documentation? https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/compute.html

Comment: Yes, the documentation does not clarify to me why one would want to do this in practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `dbplyr::collapse()` forces intermediate SQL query rendering for sub-queries.

Here is an example:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)

db <- memdb_frame(a = c(3, 4, 1, 2), b = c(5, 1, 2, NA))


# No subquery
db %>% 
  mutate(a = 2 * b) %>% 
  # collapse() %>%
  arrange(a) %>%
  show_query()
#> <SQL>
#> SELECT 2.0 * `b` AS `a`, `b`
#> FROM `dbplyr_001`
#> ORDER BY `a`

# Intermediate sql used as subquery
db %>% 
  mutate(a = 2 * b) %>% 
  collapse() %>%
  arrange(a) %>%
  show_query()
#> <SQL>
#> SELECT *
#> FROM (
#> SELECT 2.0 * `b` AS `a`, `b`
#> FROM `dbplyr_001`
#> )
#> ORDER BY `a`
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer @giovanni, this is helpful. From an SQL or backend perspective, are there performance improvements to be had from using such an approach?

It seems tome that the results are the same, so I'm still not sure why someone would do this in practice.

Comment: In general, queries with subqueries are less performant than equivalent queries that do not employ subqueries.

Comment: From `?dbplyr::sql_render()`: "you can place a bare table name in a subquery and ORDER BY does not work in subqueries."